# Creating batches from custom dataset of images in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm reading a list of .jpg images from  disk, and I wanted to split it in several batches. But I got a ValueError while trying to create the first batch.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

images_list = []
for i in range(6):
    image = tf.read_file("{0}.jpg".format(i))
    image_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image_tensor = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image_tensor)
    image_tensor = tf.image.resize_images(image_tensor, 28, 28)
    image_tensor = tf.expand_dims(image_tensor, 0)
    images_list.append(image_tensor)

batches, _ = tf.train.batch(images_list, batch_size=3, enqueue_many=True, capacity=6)
```

And this is the error message:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-a07e94cddf32> in <module>()
----> 1 batches, _ = tf.train.batch(images_list, batch_size=3, enqueue_many=True, capacity=6)

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message is not linked to TensorFlow at all (you can see that the ValueError was not thrown by TensorFlow).

If you look at the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch), you can see that `tf.train.batch()` returns a list of tensors (one value in total), and you are trying to get two values when you write `batches, _ = tf.train.batch(...)`.

That is why you get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

You just have to write instead:

```py
batches = tf.train.batch(images_list, batch_size=3, enqueue_many=True, capacity=6)
```

Comment: Oh, it seems that I made a terrible stupid mistake (shame!!!)
It's strange, in the doc it's written that the output is "A list of tensors with the same number and types as tensor_list" (so in my example 6 batches).
But with 6 input tensors and a batch_size of 3, was not supposed to produce only 2 batches?

Comment: I agree, the documentation is not clear. I encourage you to read [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) to better understand how to read data. You should use **filename queues** such as `tf.train.string_input_producer(...)` before calling `tf.train.batch(...)`